# Transform array using reduce (property undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, functional-programming, reduce

I want to transform an array to regrouping all cities for the same country.
I have an array of Object

```
locations = [
{
cities: ["Paris"]
country: "France"
},
{
cities: ["Marseille"]
country: "France"
},
{
cities: ["Kiev"]
country: "Ukraine"
},
{
cities: ["Odessa"]
country: "Ukraine"
}
...
```

And I want this :

```
locations = [
{
cities: ["Paris", "Marseille"]
country: "France"
},
{
cities: ["Kiev, Odessa"]
country: "Ukraine"
},
...
```

So, my thinking is :

```
locations.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (prev.country === curr.country) {
      prev.cities.push(curr.cities[0])
      // and delete curr Object
    }
  })
```

For the first pair of equals countries, curr.cities[0] is pushed on prev.cities, but not for the next iteration :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

[![console.log(locations) - TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined][1]][1]

Comment: Can you share the values in each `cities` array and the result you're trying to get after transforming the object?

Comment: you don't return prev from reduce inner function. so in next iteration prev don't exsist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you need to return `prev` to be used in the next iterations, also, it should be initialized to `{}`. Besides, you need to take care of the initial addition of each country where an object with `cities` array should be stored:

```js
const locations = [
  { country: "France", cities: ['city1','city2'] },
  { country: "France", cities: ['city3','city4'] },
  { country: "Ukraine", cities: ['city5'] },
  { country: "Ukraine", cities: ['city6'] }
];

const res = Object.values(locations.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const { country, cities = [] } = curr;
  const [city] = cities;
  if (prev[country] && city) {
    prev[country].cities.push(city);
  } else {
    prev[country] = { country, cities: city ? [city] : [] };
  }
  return prev;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map keyed by country, and with an initially empty array as corresponding value. Then populate those arrays, and finally extract the entries from that Map. This has a linear time complexity:

```js
let locations = [{cities: ["Paris"],country: "France"},{cities: ["Marseille"],country: "France"},{cities: ["Kiev"],country: "Ukraine"},{cities: ["Odesa"], country: "Ukraine"}];

let map = new Map(locations.map(({country}) => [country, {country, cities: []}]));
for (let loc of locations) map.get(loc.country).cities.push(...loc.cities);
let res = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think to achive the desired output format you could do something like this:

```js
locations = [
  { cities: ["Paris"], country: "France" },
  { cities: ["Marseille"], country: "France" },
  { cities: ["Kiev"], country: "Ukraine" },
  { cities: ["Odesa"], country: "Ukraine" }
];

var grouped = Object.entries(
  locations.reduce((a, {country, cities}) => ({
    ...a, [country]: [...(a[country] || []), ...cities]
  }), {})
).map(([country, cities]) => ({ country: country, cities: cities }), []);
  
console.log(grouped);
```